# How can I delete comments in a rails blog app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, blogs

I'm new to rails, I have followed the Blogger tutorial from Jumpstart Labs to make a blogging app, and I am trying to implement a feature that will allow users who are logged in to delete comments on articles. 
but I keep getting confused by this error message "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy
Couldn't find Article with 'id'="

here's what I've managed so far,

this is my app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login, except: [:create]

    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]

        @comment.save

        redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
    end

    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
      @comment.destroy

      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end

    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body)
    end
end
```

and my /views/articles/show.html.erb

```
    <h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p>
  <b>Posted on <%= @article.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y") %></b>
</p>
<p>
    <% if @article.image.exists? %>
        <%= image_tag @article.image.url%>
    <% end %>
</p>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
<% if logged_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<h3>Comments (<%=@article.comments.size %>) </h3>
<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', 
collection: @article.comments %>
<p>
    Tags:
    <% @article.tags.each do |tag| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

app/views/articles/comment.html.erb

```
   <div>
      <p><b>Comment by:</b> <%= comment.author_name %></p>
      <p class="comment"><%= comment.body %></p>
      <p>Posted <%= distance_of_time_in_words(comment.article.created_at,     comment.created_at) %> later</p>
      <%= link_to 'Delete Comment',  article_comment(article, comment),   method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
   </div>
```

routes.rb

```
    Blogger::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'about', to: 'info#about'

  get 'portfolio', to: 'info#portfolio'

  get 'contact', to: 'info#contact'

    root to: 'articles#index'
    resources :articles do
        resources :comments
    end
    resources :tags
    resources :authors
    resources :author_sessions, only: [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
    get 'login' => 'author_sessions#new'
    get 'logout' => 'author_sessions#destroy'

end
```

and my articles_controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
include ArticlesHelper
before_filter :require_login, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]



def index
    @articles = Article.all
end
def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
     @article = Article.new(article_params)
     @article.save
     flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Created!"
     redirect_to article_path(@article)
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.article_id = @article.id
end

def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(article_params)
    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end

def destroy

    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Deleted!"
    redirect_to articles_path
end
```

end

Any input or advice greatly appreciated, I've been looking around google and stack overflow for a while but I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `NameError in Articles#show undefined local variable or method article` can be fixed by changing this line in **app/views/articles/_comment.html.erb** (I believe it has _)

from

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Comment',  article_comment(article, comment),   method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Comment',  article_comment_path(comment.article, comment),   method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And in **views/articles/show.html.erb**, try to change `collection: @article.comments` to `collection: @article.comments.all`.

Comment: Thank you, fixing the link_to in comment.html.erb got me past the NameError, though I'm still back at square one whenever I click my "Delete Comment"  link on my article's show page, I'm still getting the "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=" from my original post. Do you know how I can get past this error?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=" but if it helps, the error page does highlight the first line of the destroy action in my comments_controller.rb "@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])"

Comment: Could you post the log when you click "Delete Comment"? It's like `Started DELETE "blogs/..."  Parameters: { ...}`. I just want to see the link and the parameters

Comment: Ok so It looks like my rails server wasn't even updating the changes I made to views/articles/show.html.erb for some reason, so I closed the server and then ran it again and it looks like that solved the problem, I'm able to successfully delete comments! yay! :) Still not sure why the server wasn't updating like that, but I'll accept your answer as the solution to my problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get past that particular error your having you need to permit the :id and :article_id params

Add them like this

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body, :id, :article_id)
```

Comment: He doesn't use mass assignment in `destroy` method, so I think strong parameter is not the problem here

Comment: Let's see your articles controller.